# dpkg a linux-image package fails with character `~' not allowed

Tags: kernel, dpkg

```
sudo apt-get download linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
```

will download the package:

```
linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic_3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

and trying to list (or install) with:

```
dpkg --listfiles linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic_3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

returns error:

```
illegal package name: character `~' not allowed
```

Also true when following directions for Ubuntu kernel builds.
Why do the kernel version and packages have illegal characters? 
Why doesn't the Ubuntu kernel documentation (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel) say anything about the actual released kernel versioning (it says a lot of stuff that doesn't match)?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic`

Comment: linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic:
  Installed: 3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1
  Candidate: 3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong command. `dpkg --listfiles` is for installed packages, not random `.deb` files. From [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dpkg.1):

```
-L, --listfiles package-name...
  List files installed to your system from package-name.
```

So when you do `dpkg --listfiles linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic_3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1_amd64.deb`, `linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic_3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1_amd64.deb` is treated as the package name, instead of `linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic`.

Use `dpkg-deb --contents` instead:

```
$ dpkg-deb --contents linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic_3.19.0-25.26\~14.04.1_amd64.deb
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2015-07-25 05:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2015-07-25 04:52 ./lib/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2015-07-25 04:52 ./lib/firmware/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2015-07-25 04:52 ./lib/firmware/3.19.0-25-generic/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2015-07-25 04:52 ./lib/firmware/3.19.0-25-generic/korg/
-rw-r--r-- root/root     15764 2015-07-25 04:52 ./lib/firmware/3.19.0-25-generic/korg/k1212.dsp
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2015-07-25 04:52 ./lib/firmware/3.19.0-25-generic/tigon/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      2668 2015-07-25 04:52 ./lib/firmware/3.19.0-25-generic/tigon/tg3.bin
-rw-r--r-- root/root      3884 2015-07-25 04:52 ./lib/firmware/3.19.0-25-generic/tigon/tg3_tso5.bin
-rw-r--r-- root/root      7004 2015-07-25 04:52 ./lib/firmware/3.19.0-25-generic/tigon/tg3_tso.bin
...
```

---

And you don't need `sudo` to use `apt-get download`.